# Dividing time by an integer in PHP and Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, time, integer, division

I want to divide time interval by an integer in php or laravel.

```
 $vidDuration = Video::selectRaw('SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(duration))) AS total')
                  ->whereIn('id', [3,4,5])
                  ->pluck('total')
                  ->toArray();
```

The result I get from it is Array `( [0] => 00:08:18 )` so I want to divide `$vidDuration[0])` by 2 and get the result `00:04:09`. The full division of time with an integer.

Comment: Maybe `SEC_TO_TIME(SUM((TIME_TO_SEC(duration)/2)))`

Comment: (int)$vidDuration[0]/2 you can use like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dividing complex strings by something is never straight forward. But you could simply do

```
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM((TIME_TO_SEC(duration)/2))) AS total
```

because the output from a `TIME_TO_SEC()` will be a simple integer

Comment: this is done but if I want to divide by a variable then please tell me the solution

Comment: Replace `2` with `$var`

Comment: Change single quotes to double quotes